# How can I detect keypresses in my x86 C kernel OS and call a function with the keycode as a param?

Tags: c, x86, kernel, osdev

i followed a [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZQftyCk7_SeZRitx5MjBKzTtvk0pHMtp) on youtube on how to make an x86_64 kernel.
I wanted to know how i can detect keypresses in my c kernel.
For example, i want it to call a function when a key is pressed and pass the keycode as a param.

```c
void on_key_press(char* code) {
  print_str("Pressed Key: ");
  print_str(code);
}
```

*i am running on windows, i'm using docker to build and qemu to run.*

I haven't tried anything yet, as i couldn't find any resources online.
I think i need some driver to detect the codes and send them to a function, but i don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Aside: you should definitely go bigger than `char code`. Are there *any* I/O functions that use `char`? Also you've tagged this C but the `print_str` function appears to be able to detect the argument type.

Comment: @WeatherVane the `print_str` function receives `char*`. idk why it shouldn't be tagged `c`.
i either want to receive a `char*` for the name of the keyCode. or an `size_t`.

Comment: If you're making a kernel I'd expect you'd have to interface with the BIOS more directly. On older systems that involved defining an interrupt handler.

Comment: I mentioned that because `print_str(code);` isn't passing `char*`.